# getting error 500 while sending Volley Multipart post image and Params request

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I am using sending `MultipartRequest` `Volley` `Post` request, I get server error

> BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 500

The server is receiving request on **`Postman`** without problem.

Also, I used `http://httpbin.org/post` to test whether image and params are being attached, and to me everything seems ok. Can anyone help me with this. Tried searching for hours still not able to resolve this issue.

**Httpbin response**

```
{
   "args":{
      
   },
   "data":"",
   "files":{
      "image":"data:application/octet-stream;base64,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"
   },
   "form":{
      "email":"emirdeed@gmail.com",
      "emailText":"Hallo,\nes ist jetzt ganz einfach, selbst aktiv etwas gegen das Insekten- und Bienensterben und f?r mehr Biodiversit?t zu tun. Privaten G?rten und Balkonen kommt dabei eine sehr wichtige Aufgabe zu, z. B. durch die richtige Auswahl der Pflanzen. Im Anhang siehst du den ?koscan von meinem Garten, der auf www.example.de erstellt wurde. Hier kannst Du ganz einfach in der Pflanzensuche insektenfreundliche Pflanzen finden und Pflanzen per Foto bestimmen. Die Anwendung ist ?brigens kostenlos.\nVielleicht hast du ja Lust, deinen eigenen Garten auch mal zu checken.\n\nViele Gr??e,\n",
      "fromMail":"example@example.com",
      "fromName":"Amir",
      "toName":"receiver name"
   },
   "headers":{
      "Accept-Encoding":"gzip",
      "Authorization":"Bearer BAN4vrbQLvp6J5xLVx_VEY1_Pa1lNqhtLUqwRWGrvQbUh2FEwY7YQOSSAm2Ptj6nDgSltyP2qhd_7f5U6A0hl1gbm6m-1gt6qWQuM1PTkr_BqfM9KgsMTv-pECNHvcYqkytTRbC8WzgA32WDN9u3_VE_2Vqv7SEXJtd946bMFKslp_iLQfVxlalGXEm_XdonJgBGEzH83tdeJEqQ5GnjzE0HEmHoGRek911j6TwL0fUWDfXWSSW057EeKEB5krvqFdZJSSavdWeP4UM0E7PnubDieR7dSkBpk5JX8MRJ7dx0IgnWjFavTwakQdtwdqJDVzm12IHhsmOZk45YBAoc0A",
      "Content-Length":"343844",
      "Content-Type":"multipart/form-data; boundary=zoPsBEe7D03JvmRPNkldtWEY7g7cNl6QiSVpjqIE; charset=US-ASCII",
      "Host":"httpbin.org",
      "User-Agent":"Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 9; AOSP on IA Emulator Build/PSR1.180720.117)",
      "X-Amzn-Trace-Id":"Root=1-5f9722f1-20f1e81d2b9a54616d2090d7"
   },
   "json":null,
   "origin":"194.95.1.95",
   "url":"http://httpbin.org/post"
}
```

**send Volley Method**

```
private void emailFile(Bitmap bitmap) {
        File savedPdfFile = new File(getActivity().getFilesDir(), file_name_path);

         String scanEmailUrl = "https://examplebackend.sslbeta.de/api/AccountAPI/sendScanMail";
        //String scanEmailUrl = "http://httpbin.org/post";

        File file = bitmapToFile(bitmap,"example_ecoscan");

        // Add binary body
        if (file != null) {
            HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

            params.put("email", "emirdeed@gmail.com");
            params.put("emailText", emailMsgEdtText.getText().toString());
            params.put("fromMail", "example@example.com");
            params.put("fromName", "Amir");
            params.put("toName", "receiver name");

            MultipartRequest myRequest = new MultipartRequest(getActivity(),  file, params, scanEmailUrl, new Response.Listener<String>(){

                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Log.d("response", response);
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "email sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener(){

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError e) {
                    Log.d("ReadRdaJSONFeedTask", e.getLocalizedMessage() == null ? "" : e.getLocalizedMessage());
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), e.getLocalizedMessage() == null ? "" : e.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            });

            myRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(10000, 0, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

            RequestQueueSingleton.getInstance(getContext()).addToRequestQueue(myRequest);

        }

    }
```

**MultipartRequest Class**

```
public class MultipartRequest extends Request<String> {

    private MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();

    private static final String FILE_PART_NAME = "image";

    private final Response.Listener<String> mListener;
    private final File file;
    private final HashMap<String, String> params;
    private Context context;

    public MultipartRequest(Context context, File file, HashMap<String, String> params, String url, Response.Listener<String> listener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
        super(Method.POST, url, errorListener);

        mListener = listener;
        this.file = file;
        this.params = params;
        this.context = context;
        buildMultipartEntity();
    }

    private void buildMultipartEntity() {
        entity.addPart(FILE_PART_NAME, new FileBody(file));
        try {
            for (String key : params.keySet()) {
                entity.addPart(key, new StringBody(params.get(key)));
            }
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            VolleyLog.e("UnsupportedEncodingException");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getBodyContentType() {
        return entity.getContentType().getValue();
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try {
            entity.writeTo(bos);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            VolleyLog.e("IOException writing to ByteArrayOutputStream");
        }
        return bos.toByteArray();
    }

    /**
     * copied from Android StringRequest class
     */
    @Override
    protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
        String parsed;
        try {
            parsed = new String(response.data, HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            parsed = new String(response.data);
        }
        return Response.success(parsed, HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
        ApplicationUser user = PreferencesUtility.getUser(context);
        Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
        headers.put("Authorization", "Bearer " + user.getToken());
        return headers;
    }

    @Override
    protected void deliverResponse(String response) {
        mListener.onResponse(response);
    }
}
```

**`Postman` working example, `httpbin.org/post` response**

```
{
    "args": {},
    "data": "",
    "files": {
        "image": "data:image/png;base64,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"
    },
    "form": {
        "email": "example@gmail.com",
        "emailText": "some text",
        "fromMail": "example@example.com",
        "fromName": "Amir",
        "toName": "receiver name"
    },
    "headers": {
        "Accept": "*/*",
        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
        "Authorization": "Bearer UkNQV8NSJV7DIZzVhMHXJvH2SCdTtdPL0SVCBP5tj3cSgNnAgdhBYdA8HFb0NUHZYzWkYH0Tf3bdTLU5isyJTcWCPFIQQhDHG_SMkO_WIszDl0T0mYj-kkSyErz4nZtSKZy8I_fnbFyjAuDEEW1khdt1ct1f-Dp5t-vyfHj9hlgyJlyF3d5iroYsLRRbu_gTWD39sWiQR1T31aZTst5kMIz6M9KOtvGAVZIep7soY8LnIN59aMC0ShpmmooIZh21hYhaGGD2NRivZnVHd--dlWUYeQSMayqtTUEF4NqpjcHmLJvK61ZwobM-7ORwNc4R5iBS-6PNVKbrmsE13BGQNw",
        "Content-Length": "178556",
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------295330887852083842487601",
        "Host": "httpbin.org",
        "Postman-Token": "7a09709e-996b-47e6-9366-329f4c55bfc9",
        "User-Agent": "PostmanRuntime/7.26.5",
        "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-5f97d311-48bdfe9b61cff3977e2788a8"
    },
    "json": null,
    "origin": "194.95.1.95",
    "url": "http://httpbin.org/post"
}
```

Comment: Please also add the working request from Postman. Probably Postman is setting some headers differently

Comment: One thing I see, is that the image you are sending is a`data:application/octet-stream;` maybe the server is expecting a concrete image type like `data:image/jpeg;` or `data:image/png;`  Postman sets the correct type here ...

Comment: Thanks @derpirscher for your comment. I have attached json response of postman. Also i will update if it works with changing image type.